# Where did my hard drive space go?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, fedora

After installing a 120GB SSD on my computer, I ran `df -h` and got this result:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G  3.8G   43G   9% /
devtmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.5G  152K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.5G  860K  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    1.5G   16M  1.5G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M  101M  348M  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   58G  5.6G   49G  11% /home
```

In the nautilus filesystem viewer, it shows my computer as only having at total capacity of 52.7 GB. Why isn't it 120GB? [edit: In the system preferences, details pane shows hard drive space of 114 GB]

I assume this is because the 120GB was split between the `fedora-root` partition and the `fedora-home` partition. Is this correct? If so, should I resize the `fedora-root` partition and give more space to `fedora-home`? I want to get as much space out of the 120GB hard drive as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume this is because the 120GB was split between the `fedora-root` partition and the `fedora-home` partition. Is this correct?

Yes.

> If so, should I resize the `fedora-root` partition and give more space to `fedora-home`? I want to get as much space out of the 120GB hard drive as possible.

The root partition is where all installed programs will reside. The home partition will hold (parts of) your personal data, as well as cache and configuration files.

If you have a traditional HDD as well, 58 GiB should be enough for the home partition. The is no need to store your entire media library on your fastest hard drive.

If you do not have additional drives, I'd make the root partition a bit smaller. 32 GiB are usually enough. All depends on how many programs you are going to install.

Finally, you don't **need** two partitions. If you mount the home partition elsewhere, you can copy the contents of the home partition inside the `/home` folder of the root partition and remove the home partition completely. Having a single partition has obvious advantages, but it makes reinstalls a little bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that fedora split the drive in `/` and `/home`.
Normally around 10-20 GB for / is enough - and the rest for /home.
But this depends on the number of programs you have installed.

**[Comment @Dennis]**
Having a /home partition makes most sense if multiple users are working on one computer/server. If you are the only user or know the other users, only one partition is needed. If another user fills up the drive and it is split, he/she can only fill up the /home partition and not the / partition.

Comment: the difference between 114GB and 120GB is because the hard drive manufacturer sees 120TB as 120*1000*1000 MB. Nautilus seems to use 1024 (2^10): 120 * 1000 * 1000 / 1024 / 1024 = 114